# JQuery On and Live

Tags: jquery, live

I have a JavaScript file - MyJavascript.js - that is included in various web applications. The problem is that in one application I use JQuery v1.5.1, where the "Live" function works just fine, but in another application, since I use Bootstrap, I use v2.1.1., where "on"  works and "live" doesn't.

Is there any way that I can write my JS file in a way that it works for Both the versions of JQuery?

++ Abhay

Comment: Can you not upgrade version of jQuery in the older application? It it would be simpler and better in the long run.

Comment: I agree with you. But doing that is cracking up a lot of plugins in the old version. Tough task !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

The problem of attaching the events to Dynamically Added elements still remained. So, I wrote down a Javascript function instead as follows :

```js
function compatibleOn(event, selector, handler) {
  if (typeof jQuery().on === 'function') {
    $(document).on(event, selector, handler);
  } else {
    $(selector).live(event, handler);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always extend the jQuery object with your own functions to make things possible.

A solution for this problem would be the following function:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.compatibleOn = function(event, handler){
    if(typeof jQuery().on === 'function')
    {
      $(this).on(event, handler);
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).live(event, handler);
    }
  }
})( jQuery );
```

You can now just call

```
jQuery('.my-link').compatibleOn('click', function(){alert('TEST');});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/acs884t2/1/ for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function in both versions. Another option would be to test for the existence of the `on()` function in the jQuery object and create it if it is missing using either `delegate()` or `live()` inside your patched in function.

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
if(!$.fn.on) {
    $.fn.on = function(event, selector, handler) {
        if (arguments.length == 2) {
            return this.bind(event, selector);
        } else {
            return this.delegate(selector, event, handler);
        }
    };
}
```

Edited to support more of the `on()` functionality